# std::map: Creating/replacing an element when it is not default-constructible

Tags: c++, std, stdmap, deleted-functions

Suppose you have a class which is not default constructible.

```
class A {
  private:
    int a;
  public:
    A() = delete;
    A(int a0) : a(a0) {}
};
```

Now, we have some map Int --> A, `std::map<int, A> mapping`. Let's say we want to create a new mapping for some key 0, and if the key exists, we want to replace the old value. The way to do this for default-constructible classes is this:

```
mapping[0] = A(4);
```

This will however fail for class A, because operator[] first constructs a default instance of A, and only then will it assign the value of `A(4)`. One way to do this in general (i.e. for non-default-constructible classes) is this:

```
auto it = mapping.find(0);
if (it == mapping.end()) {
  mapping.insert(0, A(4));
}
else {
  it->second = A(4);
}
```

My question is: is this really the (C++) intended way to do this? I feel this cannot be right; as a programmer I do not want to write so much code for so little. But there seems to be no simple way out: I have looked up common map methods (insert, emplace, emplace_hint) and all of them do nothing if the key is already present.

Comment: Typically, if you find something is too much code, you can fix the problem by making it a function. Suddenly, the task that is takes too many lines to write can be done in a single line.

Comment: Yes. But I believe that this is a pretty common task, so I would assume C++ commitee (or whoever designs the language) have a solution to this.

Comment: @buj: "*I believe that this is a pretty common task*" That's the problem. C++, as a language and as a standard library, generally does not like it when a type is not default constructible. It is possible to make and use such types, but broadly speaking, your ability to use such types in generic C++ code will be limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have looked up common map methods (insert, emplace, emplace_hint) and all of them do nothing if the key is already present.

C++17 have addressed that point with [`std::map::insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign):

> ```
> template <class M>
> pair<iterator, bool> insert_or_assign(const key_type& k, M&& obj);
> ```
>
> If a key equivalent to `k` already exists in the container, assigns `std::forward<M>(obj)` to the `mapped_type` corresponding to the key `k`. If the key does not exist, inserts the new value as if by insert, constructing it from `value_type(k, std::forward<M>(obj)`).

This makes

```
auto it = mapping.find(0);
if (it == mapping.end()) {
  mapping.insert(0, A(4));
}
else {
  it->second = A(4);
}
```

looks like

```
mapping.insert_or_assign(0, A(4));
```

[full program demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0742bcd225439c1b)